# Using WhatsApp on my phone, from my laptop, with no internet connection from phone?

Tags: android, tethering, whatsapp

- I can use tethering between my laptop and my phone, allowing my laptop to use the phone's internet connection.
- I can use the WhatsApp client on my phone even when the phone has no internet connection - the messages are sent when the connection returns.
- I can use WhatsApp Web on my tethered laptop, but only when the phone has an internet connection.

Is there a way to somehow use WhatsApp Web (or similar) on my tethered laptop, *even when the phone has lost its internet connection*, letting the phone send the messages when a connection returns?

## Edit

To clarify, I'm looking for a way of remote-controlling the WhatsApp process on my phone. My PC and my phone can talk to each other through tethering even if the phone's internet connection is currently broken; why can't I use that to control the WhatsApp process on my phone?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. According to [WhatsApp's FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/web/28080002/?category=5245260):

> Your session on WhatsApp Web is an extension of WhatsApp on your phone. WhatsApp Web connects to your phone to sync messages, thus you can see all messages on both devices. The first requirement to being able to use WhatsApp Web is an active WhatsApp account on your smartphone.
>
> If you cannot connect to WhatsApp on your phone to send and receive messages, then you will not be able to use WhatsApp Web.

Comment: I think you've perhaps misunderstood my question. I understand that WhatsApp Web is an extension of WhatsApp on my phone. But what I want to be able to do is use the WhatsApp app (a process on my phone) from some kind of process on my PC. The phone process would send the messages later. If my PC can talk to my phone using tethering, then why can't I use it to control WhatsApp? It's faster typing on my PC than on my phone!

Comment: From what I understand, WhatsApp Web (as well as WhatsApp Desktop apps) is simply mirroring what's on your phone, but **only if the phone is connected to the internet (Wi-Fi, LTE...)**. The fact that your computer uses or not the phone's connection, doesn't play any role here.

Comment: I just made a test: opening WhatsApp Web, then putting my phone in plane mode. I wrote a message in WhatsApp Web, and of course it wasn't sent. When I deactivated plane mode on my phone, the message was sent.

Comment: The text is on my WhatsApp app on my phone. I want to use/see that data from my phone on my laptop without going via the Internet (ie without using WhatsApp Web).

Comment: Sadly, that is not possible. Only WhatsApp can access a WhatsApp conversation, especially because it's encrypted.

Comment: It's a shame that the WhatsApp android app can't provide a way to be remote controlled.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is by design from WhatsApp to require the phone to handle the communication and therefor the phone needs to be connected to the internet. When you disconnect the internet from the phone, it will take a while before the webclient knows, and during that time you can queue up sending messages, but that's it.

This is how WhatsApp designed it, and there isn't really a way to counteract this, other than using other software (not whatsapp). WhatsApp is software used for a phone, and by using this method, it is enforced. WhatsApp does not want their users to use the web only. That's why all clients that are not phones require the phone to be active as well.

Comment: I think you've perhaps misunderstood my question. I understand that WhatsApp Web is an extension of WhatsApp on my phone. But what I want to be able to do is use the WhatsApp app (a process on my phone) from some kind of process on my PC. The phone process would send the messages later. If my PC can talk to my phone using tethering, then why can't I use it to control WhatsApp? It's faster typing on my PC than on my phone!

Comment: Whatsapp is designed to only work if the app has access to internet. That's how WhatsApp wants it to work. I understand your question, but there's no alternative answer.